# How can i reach the results in CPLEX, when CPLEX is stopped manually?

Tags: c#, cplex

When I stop the running model in CPLEX, I could not take the values of the decision variables even if there exist some feasible solutions. Is there any way to keep the values of the decision variables when running model is stopped in CPLEX?

Comment: How are you running CPLEX? Via the command line interface or via one of the APIs (e.g. via C#)? What have you tried so far, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refdotnetcplex/html/M_ILOG_CPLEX_Cplex_Use.htm

help ?

See similar question at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ef79ea8a-9483-4f22-9e6b-cb02fbbd6285&ps=25